# Canvas game framerate drop

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Good evening, first i'm not sure i should post this here, since i have litteraly no idea what's wrong here (only clue is it happened after i moved all my variables at the top of my code while trying to "clean up" a little).

but here is the problem: i've created a [canvas game](https://jsfiddle.net/izaakh/Ldpe3102/1/) and after moving my variables (i think) i started getting major framedrops. Game weighs less than 20Ko, images are super tiny and simple, i have a for loop in the update loop but it never seemed to be a problem (it's not infinite) so in short i do not know what's wrong here

here is a bit of code since links to code "must be accompanied by code" (dont know what's up with that)

```
for (var i = 0; i<boxes.length; i++){
    ctx.rect(boxes[i].x, boxes[i].y, boxes[i].width, boxes[i].height);
    var col = coli(player,boxes[i])
};
```

i've tried different things, like disabling functions (anim and colision), friction and gravity but nothing seems to have any effect, and i dont know that much about the dom except how to look at my own variables so i havent found anything with firebug.

Really hope someone has an idea

Comment: Debug questions are not suited for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `ctx.beginPath()` before using `ctx.rect`, `moveTo`, `lineTo`, `arc`, and any function you need to use `ctx.stroke()` or `ctx.fill()` to see.

`beginPath` tell the canvas 2D context that you wish to start a new shape. If you do not do this you end up adding more and more shapes each update.

From your fiddle

```
function update() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  ctx.fillStyle = pat;
  //===============================================================
  ctx.beginPath()  // <=== this will fix your problem. It removes all the
  //                       previous rects
  //===============================================================
  for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
    ctx.rect(boxes[i].x, boxes[i].y, boxes[i].width, boxes[i].height);
    // or use ctx.fillRect(...
    var col = coli(player, boxes[i])
  };
  ctx.fill();
```

Comment: Oh yeah it worked thanks a lot this started to haunt my nights haha.